# How do I set up this double integral and then solve it.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If $R$ is the region $\{(x,y)|x+y\ge a, x^2+y^2\le a^2\},$ with $a>0$, evaluate the integral $$\iint_Rxy\;dA$$ the answer should be in terms of $a$.

I started with drawing out the regions that describe the inequalities that describe the region. I don't know how to graph with LaTex, but I can describe it. $$x+y\ge a$$ is just $y\ge a -x$ which is a dotted $y=-x$ line with the upper section shaded. As $a$ gets bigger, the line would be shifted up parallel to the $y$-axis.

$$x^2+y^2\le a^2$$ is a set of circles centered at the origin that don't include the boundary itself. As $a^2$ increases, the radius of the circle increases.

I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: You seem to use different conditions in defining $R$ and later in $x^2 + y^2 \leq a^2$. Is $a$ squared or not?

Comment: I'd use polar coordinates to calculate the integral over the entire quarter-circle and then use rectangular coordinates to calculate the integral of the triangle that's not included in  $R$.  Subtract one from the other and you have your answer.

Comment: You have edited your question, but you still have $x^2+y^2\leqslant a$ at one place and $x^2+y^2\leqslant a^2$ at another place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use polar coordinates to calculate the quarter circle and use the normal way to calculate the triangle area.

$x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$. $J=r$. $0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2},0\leq r\leq a$.

$$I_{1}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{0}^{a}r^{3}\sin\theta\cos\theta\mathrm{d}r$$
$$I_{2}=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{a-x}xy\mathrm{d}y$$

I give another direct solution to make it easier to understand from the geometric view.

$$I=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\int_{-x+a}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}xy\mathrm{d}y$$

Let me explain how to confirm the area on $xy$-plane by $x^2+y^2\leq a^2$ and $x+y\geq a$, even without drawing.
At first we should determine the range of $x$. One may assume $-a\leq x\leq a$ but it's wrong. Because by the second inequality $x+y\geq a\Leftrightarrow x\geq-y+a$. Note that by $x^2+y^2\leq a^2$ get the maximum of $y$ is $a$, which is the situation $x=0$. Someone would say how about the minimum $y=-a$? If let $y=-a$ you can find $x$ will be not smaller than $2a$, it conflicts with the upper bound $a$. So the lower bound of $x$ is just $0$. Hence the range of $x$ is $0\leq x\leq a$.

For the $y$-component, it's more easier. By the first inequality we know $-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\leq y\leq\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$. However, by $y\geq-x+a$, then compare to get $(-x+a)-(-\sqrt{a^2-x^2})\geq0$, finally determines the range of $y=y(x)$ is $-x+a\leq y\leq\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$.

Comment: That makes sense. Can you help me understand how the set is defined? From how it reads, I would think that $x+y\ge a$ defines $x$ and $x^2+y^2\le a^2$ defines the $y$. I don't mean how it relates to the problem, just trying to better understand set notation.

Comment: Okay. The set $x^2+y^2\leq a^2$ is the whole circle centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $a$, including its interior and boundary. The line $x+y\geq a$ can be interpreted as $y\geq-x+a$, it is the straight line with slope $-1$, you can denote point $(0,a)$ and $(a,0)$ and connect them together. $y\geq-x+a$ is the upper part of the line.

Comment: By the way I'm not sure what you said meaning, do you want to know how to describe the area by drawing on paper?

Comment: My confusion is coming from not understanding how the $x$ component of $(x,y)$ could be defined by $x+y\ge a$ and how the $y$ component by $x^2+y^2\le a^2$. I understand the graphs of the two inequalities, but I don't understand how they can define a point $(x,y)$.

Comment: I improved my answer and I hope it will help you.